# Mysql.Connect python создает неугодные кавычки

Tags: mysql, python, mysqlconnector

Дообр день, уважаемые знатоки!
Я использую mysqlConnector и python 3.6.5

В python у меня есть лист:

```
zipped = [('akamaitechnologies.com', 8221, 0), ('akamaitechnologies.com', 2053, 0), ('googleusercontent.com', 1119, 0), ('1e100.net', 3999, 0), ('1e100.net', 2819, 0)]`
```

Также у меня есть простая таблица для записи информации:

```
CREATE TABLE `dns` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dnsname` text,
    `inbytes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `outbytes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

И мой *великолепный* код:

```
#one function for connect & execute query
def mysql_conn2(fhost, finb, foutb):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=mysql_user, password=mysql_password, database=mysql_database, host=mysql_host)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT into dns (`dnsname`,`inbytes`,`outbytes`) VALUES(%s,%s,%s);", (fhost, finb, foutb))
    cnx.close()

#my script, that i have ro run
for item in zipped:
    host = str(item[0])
    inb = str(item[1])
    outb = str(item[2])
    print(host,inb, outb)
    mysql_conn2(host,inb,outb)
```

Когда я проверяю записи в таблице, то там совершенно пусто! (при этом, если добавить  руками - всё ОК).

Я задебажил скрипт - и увидел это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка - экранированные строки в  cursor.statement property, но почему?

Потом добавил руками запись в таблицу - и, о чудо, значение AUTO_INCREMENT-поля выдало отличное от `1`-числа!

Как можно заэкранировать строки или может быть я делаю что-то не так?
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Показывает все правильно. Если посмотрите выше, то увидите _executed с текстом вашего запроса. В добавок не вызывает ошибки при работе с БД. Надо включать логи запросов в mysql и смотреть, какие запросы реально выполняются. Подозрение, что у вас включен механизм транзакций и после вставки транзакция не коммитится

Comment: Дайте угадаю: у вас не включен автокоммит, а после insert'а никакого явного коммита не случилось и поэтому ничего не сохранилось? А про экранированные строки это бред конечно, это просто дебаггер выводит строку в виде строки

Comment: autocommit=1 : `set autocommit=1;`:  
выполнил - без изменений

autocommit=0 : `set autocommit=0;`:  
выполнил - без изменений

Если добавляю вручную через подключение `mysql -h localhost ....` - всё ОК
Скрипт при запуске в базу не пишет - просто увеличивает id_dns (стоит `AUTO_INCREMENT`)


`
Выставил в `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
`

Но там пусто.  
MariaDB "из коробки".. `Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.1`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, разобрался с автокоммитами!

Смотрим документацию:

> https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-connect-python-programs-mariadb

Добавляем:

```
cnx.commit()
```